# Dice values still concatenating after using parseInt/parseFloat

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to javascript and i'm trying to add values from a thrown dice using the click event listener. I have tried using parseInt/parseFloat to sum the numbers and show the values using inner.html but they keep concatenating. Here's my code

```
const dice=document.getElementsByClassName("btn-roll")[0];
let diceImg=document.querySelector("#dice-1");
let diceImg2=document.querySelector("#dice-2");
let p1CurrentScore=document.getElementById("current-0");


    dice.addEventListener("click",function(){
    let random1=Math.floor(Math.random()* 6) +1;
    let random2=Math.floor(Math.random()* 6) +1;
    diceImg.src="dice-" + random1 +".png";
    diceImg2.src="dice-" + random2 +".png";
    let totalDice=random1+random2;
    let total=0;
    total= total + (p1CurrentScore.innerHTML+=totalDice);
    parseInt(total);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a `total` variable since that value is being stored in `p1CurrentScore.innerHTML`. What you want to do is set `p1CurrentScore.innerHTML` equal to its previous value plus `totalDice`.

Ultimately you want your listener to look something like the following:

```js
dice.addEventListener("click",function(){
  let random1=Math.floor(Math.random()* 6) +1;
  let random2=Math.floor(Math.random()* 6) +1;
  diceImg.src = "dice-" + random1 + ".png";
  diceImg2.src = "dice-" + random2 + ".png";
  let totalDice=random1+random2;

  p1CurrentScore.innerHTML=parseInt(p1CurrentScore.innerHTML) + totalDice
})
```

Here is an example: https://470290.playcode.io

Answer (score 1):

Value of p1CurrentScore.innerHTML is a string and when you sum it, concatenating will be done and you get string as a result. Remember that when you are summing string and number you get concatenated string. So you need to parse that:

```
total= total + ((parseInt(p1CurrentScore.innerHTML))+=totalDice);
```

On the other hand if you subtract number from string which value is number it will be automatically converted to number. So you could do also something like `(p1CurrentScore.innerHTML-0).`
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `parseInt` to transform the text before you use the text in a math operation.

Like this:

```
const dice=document.getElementsByClassName("btn-roll")[0];
let diceImg=document.querySelector("#dice-1");
let diceImg2=document.querySelector("#dice-2");
let p1CurrentScore=document.getElementById("current-0");

dice.addEventListener("click",function(){
    let random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 6) +1;
    let random2 = Math.floor(Math.random()* 6) +1;
    diceImg.src = "dice-" + random1 + ".png";
    diceImg2.src = "dice-" + random2 + ".png";
    let totalDice = random1 + random2;
    let total = 0;
    total = total + (parseInt(p1CurrentScore.innerHTML) += totalDice); // -> Use parseInt before the operation
    // parseInt(total); -> Not necessary
})
```